# reason a font face would appear different as heading vs. normal text

Tags: css, font-face, webfonts

Okay I have a font-face that I am using as part of a website (just for nav. and a header/logo)  here is a link to the font file http://www.dafont.com/bad-grunge.font (I typically would never use something like this but client insists)

Now The strangest thing is happening and I did some googling for a reason but came up blank and am curious if anyone can explain why the browser is rendering the font much differently as a heading rather then just normal text here is an [example proving the bug](http://www.benjaminthomsen.ca/wp-content/themes/Shuttershot/proof.html) 
Any explanation as to why this is happening would be awesome (I clearly no my semantically incorrect solution) but why is this happening at all?
... I have checked on latest versions of both firefox and chrome any explanation or theory would be greatly appreciated

Comment: soooo verbose.. show us code plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `h1` tag for your header for default it has this property

```
font-weight:bold
```

If you change this in your css then it will render as the normal font:

```
h1 {
   font-weight:normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On Chrome, the only differences I am seeing are a result of the bold `font-weight` applied to the tag via the user-agent default `h1` CSS styling. If I set the font weight to `normal`, they look the same.

The bold styling comes from the default for the tag. If you use a reset css, it would not look like that. This is the one I like: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css

Or, you can just do this to fix it:

```
h1 {
    font-weight: normal; 
}
```

Comment: thanks ... excepting the other answer as says same thing posted slightly before you but give ya an upvote as welcom to community